# Why does Ubuntu package node.js packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, nodejs

I've been looking through [this list of node.js packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=node) provided by Ubuntu, and it's confused me a little. Why do any of these exist beyond node.js and npm itself?

The majority of these packages (e.g., array-flatten and friends, connect, etc) are available in npm already itself and I imagine they would be the preferred way for installation.